# Cant' install MVC4 Dependency fail

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

i'm trying  to install mvc4 but i get the following log error:

```
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9817844
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9817844 responded with 302
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 175
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Mon, 17 Jun 2013 11:24:38 GMT
Location: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.5/webproductlist.xml
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Set-Cookie: MC1=GUID=b4511e51de8f924394ee78596ed5580e&HASH=511e&LV=20136&V=3; domain=microsoft.com; expires=Sun, 03-Oct-2010 07:00:00 GMT; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 17 Jun 2013 11:25:37 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.5/webproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "2a7fb72c9551ce1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
VTag: 279336430300000000
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 17 Jun 2013 11:25:38 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\anna.nguyen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\-1250132447.xml.temp
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID WIF
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID identity
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID federation
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID claims
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID authentication
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 1, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.5/webapplicationlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.5/webapplicationlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "99645fe18968ce1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
VTag: 438550830300000000
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 17 Jun 2013 11:25:38 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\anna.nguyen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\1257519080.xml.temp
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Could not resolve keyword ID ApplicationSpotlight
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 1, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Sucessfully loaded the feed 'https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.5/webapplicationlist.xml' after preprocessing, location on disk: 'C:\Users\anna.nguyen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\preprocessor\1257519080.xml'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.5/mediaproductlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.5/mediaproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Last-Modified: Thu, 14 Feb 2013 18:07:10 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "f97d7c1bdeace1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
VTag: 279315933100000000
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 17 Jun 2013 11:25:39 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\anna.nguyen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\-645085719.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 1, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Sucessfully loaded the feed 'https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.5/mediaproductlist.xml' after preprocessing, location on disk: 'C:\Users\anna.nguyen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\preprocessor\-645085719.xml'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.5/ToolsProductList.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.5/ToolsProductList.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "e0a29fbe9e63ce1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
VTag: 791550931600000000
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 17 Jun 2013 11:25:39 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\anna.nguyen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\-278528821.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 1, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Sucessfully loaded the feed 'https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.5/ToolsProductList.xml' after preprocessing, location on disk: 'C:\Users\anna.nguyen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\preprocessor\-278528821.xml'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Loading product xml from: https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.5/enterpriseproductlist.xml
DownloadManager Information: 0 : https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.5/enterpriseproductlist.xml responded with 304
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
Cache-Control: max-age=900
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "a744a9fbddace1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
VTag: 279403132600000000
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By: ARR/2.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 17 Jun 2013 11:25:39 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Remote file has not changed, using local cached file: C:\Users\anna.nguyen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\-1611415340.xml.temp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Filtering by majorOS: 6, minorOS: 1, majorSP: 1, minorSP: 0, productType: 1, architecture: x64
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Sucessfully loaded the feed 'https://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/4.5/enterpriseproductlist.xml' after preprocessing, location on disk: 'C:\Users\anna.nguyen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\preprocessor\-1611415340.xml'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Sucessfully loaded the feed 'https://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9817844' after preprocessing, location on disk: 'C:\Users\anna.nguyen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\preprocessor\-1250132447.xml'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Getting ratings file from http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9752395
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Contextual entry products: MVC4VS2010_Loc
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product ASP.NET MVC 4 with Language Packs (August 2012) (MVC4Vs2010_Loc) to cart
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Contextual navigation to product 'MVC4Vs2010_Loc'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9752395 responded with 302
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 203
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Mon, 17 Jun 2013 11:24:41 GMT
Location: http://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/WebPI.ashx?command=getatomfeedwithavgratingquery
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
Set-Cookie: MC1=GUID=2e6a9644dd23c04c979d64e339044f7b&HASH=4496&LV=20136&V=3; domain=microsoft.com; expires=Sun, 03-Oct-2010 07:00:00 GMT; path=/
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 17 Jun 2013 11:25:40 GMT


DownloadManager Information: 0 : Ratings file loaded successfully
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding product 'MVC4Vs2010_Loc'
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'MVC4Vs2010_Loc_Only
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Adding dependency product 'MVC4VS2010_Only
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Setting current install to 1
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting install sequence
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Downloading file 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/F/6/2F63CCD8-9288-4CC8-B58C-81D109F8F5A3/AspNetMVC4Setup.exe' to: C:\Users\anna.nguyen\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpA0A7.tmp
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Content-disposition header: attachment
DownloadManager Information: 0 : File 'C:\Users\anna.nguyen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\MVC4VS2010_Only\82BCBAE192F8CB875C814821A536C959F85D4727\AspNetMVC4Setup.exe' already exists, deleting old copy of the file
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Moving downloaded file 'C:\Users\anna.nguyen\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpA0A7.tmp' to: C:\Users\anna.nguyen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\MVC4VS2010_Only\82BCBAE192F8CB875C814821A536C959F85D4727\AspNetMVC4Setup.exe
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Starting EXE command for product 'ASP.NET MVC 4 Installer (VS 2010)- Default Locale'. Commandline is: 'C:\Users\anna.nguyen\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers\MVC4VS2010_Only\82BCBAE192F8CB875C814821A536C959F85D4727\AspNetMVC4Setup.exe /q /log C:\Users\ANNA~1.NGU\AppData\Local\Temp\MVC4VS2010_Only_install.htm'. Process Id: 1700
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Install exit code for product 'ASP.NET MVC 4 Installer (VS 2010)- Default Locale' is '-2147023254'
DownloadManager Error: 0 : Install return code for product 'ASP.NET MVC 4 Installer (VS 2010)- Default Locale' is Failure
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product ASP.NET MVC 4 Installer (VS 2010)- Default Locale done install completed
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Increasing current install to 2
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Dependency failed for product 'ASP.NET MVC 4 Language Packs Installer'. Skipping install
DownloadManager Warning: 0 : Dependency failed for product 'ASP.NET MVC 4 with Language Packs (August 2012)'. Skipping install
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product ASP.NET MVC 4 Language Packs Installer had a dependency fail. Increasing install product to 3
DownloadManager Information: 0 : Product ASP.NET MVC 4 with Language Packs (August 2012) had a dependency fail. Increasing install product to 4
```

I have done the following:

Install using http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4

Installed SP1 for visual studio 2010 (restarted)

Tried the standalone install - http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30683

Tried install the needed MVC 4 components using NuGet. - http://nuget.org/packages/aspnetmvc

Checked that I don t have .NET Framework 4.5 Developer Preview (I do have .Net Framework 4.5)

Not sure what to try next - any ideas -? thanks

Comment: What VS2010 and OS version do you have?